# Visual Studio executes something when i try to build it. How do i find out the code that stays behind this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

As in title, I downloaded a program from github, but when i try to build it, it says:

> The command ""E:\LoLNotes\LoLNotes\Properties\GitExport.exe"
>   "E:\LoLNotes\" "E:\LoLNotes\LoLNotes\"" exited with code 2.

GitExport.exe doesn't work because i have no git installed. But i want to know, how do i find a place in program sources, where that code is being executed? Simple ctrl-f and searching through solution doesn't work, so i think it is hidden somewhere in the configuration files maybe? Does anyone have any idea where it could be?

Comment: If you found a solution in one of the answers, don't forget to accept one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could also be part of a customization to a project file (similar to what nuget does). In order to find out exactly where it is being fired, turn on project build output verbosity to Diagnostic in Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run. Then rebuild and search the output for GitExport.exe. This should give you a better context as to where it is happening.[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's probably a Post or Pre Build Event.

In the project, open "Properties", and look in the Build Events tab.

Answer (score 3):

In Solution Explorer, right click on the Project and choose Properties.  It is then in the Build Events section.